# Errors related to installing RSeQC

Tags: python

I have Python 2.7.6 installed but when running a python script (RSeQC scripts) with command:

```
$ python script.py
```

I got errors:

```
ImportError: No module named qcmodule
```

or

```
ImportError: No module named bx.bitset.
```

What prerequisites do I need to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you may need:

First,

```
sudo pip2 install qc bitsets RSeQC
```

Next,

```
sudo pip2 install --upgrade cython bx-python pysam RSeQC numpy
```

---

Alternatively,

Reinstall RSeQC:

```
sudo apt-get install libpython2.7-dev
wget 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/rseqc/RSeQC-2.6.4.tar.gz'
tar zxvf RSeQC-2.6.4.tar.gz
RSeQC-2.6.4
python ./setup.py build
sudo python ./setup.py install
```

This should build the needed modules. If the error persists, set an environment variable for the correct paths to the modules.

Comment: I am following the aforementioned commands to run RseQC on Ubuntu 14.04 but when running one of its scripts (bam_stat.py for example) I get an error as below: python bam_stat.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bam_stat.py", line 23, in <module>
    from bx.bitset import *
ImportError: No module named bx.bitset. What should I do to run it successfully?

Comment: @Karim It looks like there have been some changes on some of the newer versions so I revised these commands. Additionally, it looks like you may be able to use pip alone to do the install but if it needs it, the build should work on this newer version as well (version 2.6.4) just make sure to use python2.7 to do the job (I had no trouble with the build but pip did complain unless pip2 was used).  However, pip is supposed to install the necessary dependencies in any case needed for the build.

Comment: Thanks. After a while I could resolve the errors using the codes you provided. Thanks again

Comment: @Karim Awesome, and remember,  you can always upvote an accepted answer to show extra thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try those commands:

```
sudo pip install -U qcmodule
sudo pip install -U bx.bitset
```

Comment: I tried both of these commands but i got errors: 
Downloading/unpacking bx.bitset
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement bx.bitset
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for bx.bitset
Storing debug log for failure in /home/k/.pip/pip.log

Downloading/unpacking qcmodule
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement qcmodule
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for qcmodule
Storing debug log for failure in /home/k/.pip/pip.log

Comment: what are those errors?

Comment: sudo pip install -U qcmodule
sudo pip install -U bx.bitset